# dart flutter Database Storing/updating

Tags: database, dart, flutter

1. Is it possible to have a choice to store Database at different locations"?
   eg. on Dropbox/Google-Drive or other place and update it in real time
2. Can a database be selected from a list of Databases to use?
3. Can MongoDB be stored locally or on a server elsewhere?

Comment: "Can a database be selected from a list of Databases to use?" What does this mean? Select if you want to use `MySql`, `MongoDb`, `SqLite`, or a list of database files stored locally?

Comment: You can't use databases stored on Dropbox/Google drive, but that's not Flutter related, that's just because such storages don't allow modifying files the way databases would require.

Comment: Sorry for the confusing questions. What I meant was 'a list of database files'. I want to have Database files for different years. Looking to use a NoSql database such as MongoDb  And is it possible to store Database files other than locally?

Comment: Either store it locally, like with `sqflite` or store it on a server and provide a REST API or similar that you then access from Flutter. Usually you don't allow direct access to a database server without an HTTP server in between.